# Proving a circulant matrix is a subspace of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

We have that $C_n\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a circulant matrix of order n. So we have $$
C_n =
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_0     & \alpha_{n-1} & \dots  & \alpha_{2} & \alpha_{1}  \\
\alpha_{1} & \alpha_0    & \alpha_{n-1} &         & \alpha_{2}  \\
\vdots  & \alpha_{1}& \alpha_0    & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
\alpha_{n-2}  &        & \ddots & \ddots  & \alpha_{n-1}   \\
\alpha_{n-1}  & \alpha_{n-2} & \dots  & \alpha_{1} & \alpha_0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
The associated polynomial is $f(x) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x + \ldots + \alpha_{n-1}x^{n-1}$

How do I show that the set of $n\times n$ circulant matrices, $C_n$, is a subspace of that vector space with dimension $n$?

Comment: Note that (in the syntax of your earlier question) $f(Z_n)=C_n$.

Comment: Nice, thank you for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the three subspace axioms:

1. Contains the zero vector:

It is simple to see that $
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \dots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ is circulant.

2. Closure under addition:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_0     & \alpha_{n-1} & \dots  & \alpha_{2} & \alpha_{1}  \\
\alpha_{1} & \alpha_0    & \alpha_{n-1} &         & \alpha_{2}  \\
\vdots  & \alpha_{1}& \alpha_0    & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
\alpha_{n-2}  &        & \ddots & \ddots  & \alpha_{n-1}   \\
\alpha_{n-1}  & \alpha_{n-2} & \dots  & \alpha_{1} & \alpha_0 \\
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0     & \beta_{n-1} & \dots  & \beta_{2} & \beta_{1}  \\
\beta_{1} & \beta_0    & \beta_{n-1} &         & \beta_{2}  \\
\vdots  & \beta_{1}& \beta_0    & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
\beta_{n-2}  &        & \ddots & \ddots  & \beta_{n-1}   \\
\beta_{n-1}  & \beta_{n-2} & \dots  & \beta_{1} & \beta_0 \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_0 + \beta_0     & \alpha_{n-1} + \beta_{n-1} & \dots  & \alpha_{2} + \beta_{2} & \alpha_{1} + \beta_{1}  \\
\alpha_{1} + \beta_{1} & \alpha_0 + \beta_0    & \alpha_{n-1} + \beta_{n-1} &         & \alpha_{2} + \beta_{2}  \\
\vdots  & \alpha_{1} + \beta_{1}& \alpha_0 + \beta_0    & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
\alpha_{n-2} + \beta_{n-2}  &        & \ddots & \ddots  & \alpha_{n1} + \beta_{n-1}   \\
\alpha_{n-1} + \beta_{n-1}  & \alpha_{n-2} + \beta_{n-2} & \dots  & \alpha_{1} + \beta_{1} & \alpha_0 + \beta_0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

3. Closure under scalar multiplication:

$
c\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_0     & \alpha_{n-1} & \dots  & \alpha_{2} & \alpha_{1}  \\
\alpha_{1} & \alpha_0    & \alpha_{n-1} &         & \alpha_{2}  \\
\vdots  & \alpha_{1}& \alpha_0    & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
\alpha_{n-2}  &        & \ddots & \ddots  & \alpha_{n-1}   \\
\alpha_{n-1}  & \alpha_{n-2} & \dots  & \alpha_{1} & \alpha_0 \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
c\cdot \alpha_0     & c\cdot \alpha_{n-1} & \dots  & c\cdot \alpha_{2} & c\cdot \alpha_{1}  \\
c\cdot \alpha_{1} & c\cdot \alpha_0    & c\cdot \alpha_{n-1} &         & c\cdot \alpha_{2}  \\
\vdots  & c\cdot \alpha_{1}& c\cdot \alpha_0    & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
c\cdot \alpha_{n-2}  &        & \ddots & \ddots  & c\cdot \alpha_{n-1}   \\
c\cdot \alpha_{n-1}  & c\cdot \alpha_{n-2} & \dots  & c\cdot \alpha_{1} & c\cdot \alpha_0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

So the set of circulant matrices (subset of the vector space $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$) is indeed a subspace.